# Facebook Login SDK AppDelegate Error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk

I have a basic Share function in my App i'm setting up, we're using Xcode 7.2 with Swift 2.1.

**AppDelete.swift**

2016-01-29 09:25:17.576 MyApp[2020:104142] -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate openURL:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc791783390
2016-01-29 09:25:17.579 MyApp[2020:104142] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKApplicationDelegate openURL:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc791783390'

**Facebook Error that comes up too on**

2016-01-29 09:20:51.439 Tennis My Stats[2020:104142] FBSDKLog: Failed to send AppEvents: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            "fbtrace_id" = "G6V5e/++VOD";
            message = "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api";
            type = GraphMethodException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}

**My App Delegate Code for FB**

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

... other code ... then ...

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

**My View Controller**

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit

... other code ... then ...

@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Got the same issue. You solved it already?

Comment: Hey.. Did you find some solution?

Comment: Hello, Did you get any Solution?